# Inverse of 3x3 Matrix

Tags: calculus, matrices

Look at the image. Why 14 is written in a 1x3 position? There should be 2 there,
Also, 14 is written at 3x1. Why the change of order?

Same mistake in my book. Am I missing something here?

[image]

Comment: Did you notice the part where we talk about $C^T$, the transpose of $C$, in the last line?

Comment: there is no transpose in inverse. @JMoravitz

Comment: Read the algorithm again more carefully.  [This wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) might also shed some light on the situation.  We do in fact have a transpose occurring in the formula you cite.  $A^{-1}=\det(A)^{-1}\text{adj}(A)=\det(A)^{-1}C^T$ where $C$ is the cofactor matrix.

Comment: Right! Thank you so much. It really answered my question @JMoravitz

Answer (score 1):

The answer in the book is correct and you can check it by multiplying the matrix and the given answer for its inverse to see that the result is the identity matirix.

Notice that after finding the matrix $C$ you need to find its transpose which is $C^T$ and divide the result by the determinant.

That is what the book is doing and that is the reason behind the appearance misplacing the $14$ and $2$.